# How to change date locale when switching language in JHipster app?

Tags: angular, jhipster

Does anyone know How to change date locale when switching language in JHipster app?

thnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jhipster currently does not support formatting date/times in the selected locale. You could manipulate the date filter setup.

E.g. instead of `<td>{{user.lastModifiedDate | date:'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'}}</td>` you could use `<td>{{user.lastModifiedDate | date:'shortDate'}}</td>`. Maybe you have to provide the current locale but it should set as global application locale. See for official angular documentation for detail: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe